# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri: "", local:"soap:Envelope")

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

Hi I have generated java classes from a WSDL using wsimport.But I have written the response to a file *.xml. But now I want to read this xml file and populate the java classes that already have been generated.

I have tried:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Report.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Report rc = (Report) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
```

or

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Report.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Report rc = (Report) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("file.xml"));
```

`Report` is the class that I get as a response when I send the request

In the first case I get

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri: "", local:"soap:Envelope") Expected elements are: (<{"http://pagewhereisthewsdl.com"}CLASSES>)+
```

In the second case

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope") Expected elements are: (<{"http://pagewhereisthewsdl.com"}CLASSES>)+
```

XML is like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
              <ns3:GetReportOnlineResponse xmlns:ns2="http://pagewhereisthewsdl.com/document" xmlns:ns3="http://pagewhereisthewsdl.com/endpoint">
                 <ns2:Report>
                       ...
                 </ns2:Report>
           </ns3:GetReporteOnlineResponse>
       </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Or what can I do ?

Answer (score 9):

I believe you're not taking the SOAP envelope into account. You need to extract the body's content first.

```
String xml = "<INSERT XML>";
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Report.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Report rc = (Report) unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
```

Comment: I can't use the method `getBytes()` source is a instance of `javax.xml.transform.Source;`

Comment: the part to get the body works, but the unmarshalling fails, telling it expects nothing... Is not it a solution to register unmarshallers generated from wsdl2java ?